# Redux: fat action creators vs fat reducers for data `sanitization`?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am using data from a backend server (which I don't have control over), and the data is not reliable. For example, it's missing values for some fields, and sometimes has a wrong/unacceptable value for a certain field.

I need to `sanitize` this data on a frontend to make sure that the frontend app receives data of good quality and in an expected format.

Where is the best place to place such a logic to parse & convert data from the backend?

- `action creators` - After fetching data from the backend using `fetch` API, I can `sanitize` data and dispatch an action with `sanitized` data.
- `reducers` - After receiving an `unsanitized` data, reducers can parse them before saving them into a store.

Which one is more acceptable - `fat action creators` or `fat reducers'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the general recommendation **is** [to put as much logic as possible into reducers](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide/#put-as-much-logic-as-possible-in-reducers), in this case I would opt for doing the "sanitizing" part in the thunk as it kinda feels like still being a "part of the fetch" - but then do the "select what you really need" part (if only a part of the result is required) probably in the reducer.